# gcc 4.7 STL library deficit on pair implementation?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

The following code compiles on gcc 4.6 but not 4.7.  Is it 4.7's problem or 4.6's problem?  Compiled with -std=gnu++0x.

```
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct Z {
};

struct X {
    operator Z*() const { return nullptr; }
};

struct Y {
    Y(Z*) {}
};

int main() {
    pair<int, Y> p(make_pair(0, X()));
}
```

Error messages:

```
[hidden]$ g++-mp-4.6 -std=gnu++0x e.cpp 
[hidden]$ g++-mp-4.7 -std=gnu++0x e.cpp 
e.cpp: In function 'int main()':
e.cpp:17:37: error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<int, Y>::pair(std::pair<int, X>)'
e.cpp:17:37: note: candidates are:
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/utility:72:0,
                 from e.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:204:9: note: template<class ... _Args1, long unsigned int ..._Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> std::pair::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:204:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
e.cpp:17:37: note:   'std::pair<int, X>' is not derived from 'std::tuple<_Args1 ...>'
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/utility:72:0,
                 from e.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:153:9: note: template<class ... _Args1, class ... _Args2> std::pair::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>)
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:153:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
e.cpp:17:37: note:   cannot convert 'std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = X; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type = X; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type = int]((* & X()))' (type 'std::pair<int, X>') to type 'std::piecewise_construct_t'
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/utility:72:0,
                 from e.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:148:12: note: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&)
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:148:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:145:38: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:142:12: note: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:142:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
e.cpp:17:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/utility:72:0,
                 from e.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:136:12: note: template<class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair::pair(const _T1&, _U2&&)
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:136:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
e.cpp:17:37: note:   cannot convert 'std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = X; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type = X; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type = int]((* & X()))' (type 'std::pair<int, X>') to type 'const int&'
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/utility:72:0,
                 from e.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:131:12: note: template<class _U1, class> constexpr std::pair::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&)
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:131:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
e.cpp:17:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/utility:72:0,
                 from e.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:122:7: note: std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = Y; std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<int, Y>]
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:122:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::pair<int, X>' to 'std::pair<int, Y>&&'
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:119:17: note: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = Y; std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<int, Y>]
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:119:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::pair<int, X>' to 'const std::pair<int, Y>&'
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:116:12: note: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&)
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:116:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:113:38: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:104:26: note: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = Y]
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:104:26: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:100:26: note: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair() [with _T1 = int; _T2 = Y]
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:100:26: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: No error message, no answer. Please report what is the problem exactly, by providing the error message.

Comment: @icando: Reproducing this might require installing two compilers before compiling the short program. I think it's quite reasonable not to be bothered to do that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be rude, but 'no error message, no answer' sounds rude to me at the first place.  It just sounds like I didn't do any research, and the problem is stupid.

Comment: @icando: the only way to show that you've done your research and that your problem is not trivial is to show that in your question. Reporting the exact error message helps there. Klaim's request is perfectly reasonable, if a bit curt.

Comment: @Mat, maybe you are right.  Just half an hour ago I didn't know I am the only person who hates GCC's stupid error message, and I didn't know there are a LOT of people on SO are experts in C++ so that they can give the correct answer without trying compiling by themselves.  Maybe I mistakenly looked down upon SO a little bit, partly because half of my past questions didn't get good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shouldn't compile.

The initialisation of `p.second` requires an implicit conversion from `X` to `Y`. An implicit conversion can only involve at most one user-defined conversion The required conversion would require two; `X` to `Z*` via the conversion operator, and `Z*` to `Y` via the conversion constructor.

Initialisation of pair elements from another pair is only allowed via implicit conversions. C++11 says:

> 20.3.2/12 This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `const U&` is implicitly convertible to `first_type` and `const V&` is **implicitly convertible** to `second_type`.

and C++98 said:

> 20.2.2/4 Initializes members from the corresponding members of the argument, **performing implicit conversions** as needed.

Presumably, the older version had a bug which allowed this conversion to be considered, and that bug has been fixed in the more recent version.

Comment: That's not true, actually.  Under gcc4.7, replacing the line to ``Y y(X());'' will compile.  So gcc4.7 knows the conversion from X to Y.

Comment: @icando: The point isnt about knowing some conversion sequence, the point is about what conversion sequences are allowed to be considered in overload resolution. The compiler certainly has enough information to find a conversion sequence involving a dozen conversions, but it is simply not allowed to consider them.

Comment: @icando: `Y y(X());` is a vexing parse; it declares a function that takes a function pointer as an argument. `Y y = X();` attempts to initialise a `Y` from and `X`, and you should find that that doesn't compile.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, you made a valid point, but is still not the correct answer.  I've tested, replacing with ``X x; Y y(x);'' still compiles on both 4.6 and 4.7

Comment: @MikeSeymour, you said ``you should find that that doesn't compile'', what's the compiler you used to get that result?  Or is it just your imagination?

Comment: @icando: gcc 4.6.1. And also [gcc 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/gYZBI), if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: @icando: `Y y(x)` is valid because it only involves one implicit convertion; the final conversion to `Y` is explicit, since you are using _direct-initialisation_ syntax. If you wrote `Y y = x;`, then the conversion would fail.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, we must be living in different universe.  I tried gcc 4.6.3 and 4.7.0 on MacOSX and 4.6.2 on CentOS, none of them gave error message if I replace the lines in main function with ``X x; Y y(x);''

Comment: @icando: See my last comment. `Y y(x);` is valid; `Y y = x;` is not.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Then this doesn't answer why ``pair<int, Y> y(make_pair(0, x));'' works on gcc 4.6.3 but not 4.7.0.  Isn't that y.first(0) and y.second(x) will be used in the initialization?  How does standard say?  Does it say we should use y.second(x) or y.second = x?

Comment: @icando: I've updated the answer with details of how pair members are initialised by the conversion constructor.